# Resize JPEG image to fixed width, while keeping aspect ratio as it is

Tags: c#, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

How would you resize a JPEG image, to a fixed width whilst keeping aspect ratio? In a simple way, whilst preserving quality.

Answer (score 20):

This will scale in the vertical axis only:

```
    public static Image ResizeImageFixedWidth(Image imgToResize, int width)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = ((float)width / (float)sourceWidth);

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reducing the width by 25 percent to a fixed value, you must reduce the height by 25 percent.

If you are increasing the width by 25 percent to a fixed value, you must increasing the height by 25 percent.

It's really straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a (`double width`) variable:

```
Image imgOriginal = Bitmap.FromFile(path);
double height = (imgOriginal.Height * width) / imgOriginal.Width;
Image imgnew = new Bitmap((int)width, (int)height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgnew);
g.DrawImage(imgOriginal, new Point[]{new Point(0,0), new Point(width, 0), new Point(0, height)}, new Rectangle(0,0,imgOriginal.Width, imgOriginal.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

In the end you´ll have a new image with widthxheight, then, you´ll need to flush the graphics e save the imgnew.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are plenty of samples of this if you search for them.  Here's the one I commonly use...

```
    public static Stream ResizeGdi(Stream stream, System.Drawing.Size size)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;

        int sourceX = 0, sourceY = 0, destX = 0, destY = 0;

        float percent = 0, percentWidth = 0, percentHeight = 0;
        percentWidth = ((float)size.Width / (float)width);
        percentHeight = ((float)size.Height / (float)height);

        int destW = 0;
        int destH = 0;

        if (percentHeight < percentWidth)
        {
            percent = percentHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            percent = percentWidth;
        }

        destW = (int)(width * percent);
        destH = (int)(height * percent);

        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

        if (destW == 0
            && destH == 0)
        {
            image.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return mStream;
        }

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(destW, destH, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb))
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                //graphics.Clear(Color.Red);
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.DrawImage(image,
                    new Rectangle(destX, destY, destW, destH),
                    new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, width, height),
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            bitmap.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        mStream.Position = 0;
        return mStream as Stream;
    }
```

Example of the calling code...

```
Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

resizedStream = ImageUtility.ResizeGdi(stream, new System.Drawing.Size(resizeWidth, resizeHeight));
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on code project has found the following article. It allows for resizing of images which accepts a boolean to restrain the new image to keep the originals aspect ratio. I'm unsure of what the quality is like as no screenshots were provided. See the article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET?display=Print)