# How can I save an image to SQL with defined width and height in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I tried to upload an image and save details of the image to SQL. My SQL Table is like this:

```
Id    FirmId    FileName        FileURL              
1     12        firmlogo.png    /images/firmlogo.png
```

### .aspx:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnLogo" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="btnLogo_Click">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

### Code:

```
public void SaveImage()
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        //Save files to disk
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/" + FileName));
        //Add Entry to DataBase
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        string strQuery = "insert into FirmLogo (FileName , FileURL,FirmId) values(@FileName ,@FileURL,@FirmId)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName ", FileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileURL", "/images/" + FileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirmId", ComboFirm.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<center> <b>Image uploaded.</b></center> ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<center><b>Error.Please try again.</b></center> ");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveImage();
}
```

My question: I want image size to be width=300px, height=400px and save to my table like this

```
Id    FirmId    FileName        FileURL                 Width    Height       
1     12        firmlogo.png    /images/firmlogo.png    300      400
```

How can I add  static values  of width and height in my codes?

Comment: Do you want to detect size of the image before inserting into database?

Comment: Maybe.But I want to change detected size of image width=300px and height=400px to sql

Comment: So you want to resize image before save it?

Comment: Yes I want to resize image (300x400) before save.

Comment: You're not actually saving the image (unless there's a blob in the table that your'e not showing), you're just storing the address of the image.  With that being the case, you can't resize the image since your fully dependent on the server to source the image.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the sql statement

```
"insert into FirmLogo (FileName , FileURL,FirmId, Width ,Height) values(@FileName ,@FileURL,@FirmId, 300, 400)";
```

For resize Image :

[Resizing image proportionally in ASP.NET C# by specifying either Height or Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848497/resizing-image-proportionally-in-asp-net-c-sharp-by-specifying-either-height-or)

Comment: Sir,I want to change size of image 300x400px before saving.